# How to tell people that you are a bit different in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice

I know that 頭がおかしい means a strange peole, but would it be okay to say "私は頭がおかしいですが"? to meant "I'm a bit weird"?
My instinct said that it is quite unnatural... 
Or is it one of the sentences below? 
A. "私はちょっと変なけど。。。” 
B. "私は特別な人です。。。” 
C. "私はユニークです!"

The sentence was meant to be used in a situation like this:
"I gotta warn you, **I'm a bit strange** *(different in a good/fun way)*!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's probably weird to say that in either language (which just exemplifies your weird-ness ;) ).

In that case I think A is pretty good!

> 私はちょっと変だけど。。。

You could also say:

> 私は変人と言われるけど。。。
>
> ちょっと変わってるって言われるけど。。。
>
> 自分はちょっとズレてるっていうか。。。

Comment: Thanks for answering eventhough the question was a bit weird, haha... Hmm it's interesting that ズレてる (shift) can be meant as a shifted personality :D

Comment: Hehe, I think of it is 'different'. ;)